# Переопределить ключевые слова Python на русском языке

Tags: python

Добрый день!

Решил обучить ребенка (9 лет) программированию. Всякие игры типа Blockly уже пройдены, пора переходить к тексту. Для обучения выбрал Python, как, на мой взгляд, самый простой язык.

Для упрощения понимания хочу чтоб ребенок писал по-русски и постепенно переводить на английский. Очень порадовала возможность названия переменных и методов кириллицей. Большую часть стандартных методов я обернул в методы с русскими названиями. Остались только несколько проблем.

Без понятия, как перевести ветвления и циклы. Была идея написать функции типа

```
def ЕслиТоВыполнить(condition, code):
  if condition:
    eval(code)

ЕслиТоВыполнить(Правда, "вывести('да, это правда')")
```

Но тут есть 2 проблемы:

1. Пропадает структура ветвления, что может привести к проблемам при переходе на нормальный синтаксис.
2. Пропадает поддержка синтаксиса, так как часть кода я передаю строкой.

Второе можно исправить, передав функцию в качестве параметра. Но это приводит к новым вопросам.

Такая же ерунда с циклами и функциями. 
Кроме того мне не совсем нравятся методы И(expr1, expr2) и ИЛИ(expr1, expr2)
С классами проблем нет, так как думаю, что пока мы до них дойдём - уже будем писать по-английски.

Может, есть какая-нибудь возможность задефайнить ключевые слова? 
Вопрос "Зачем?" не обсуждается :) Я считаю, что надо максимально упростить задачу для вхождения, чтобы не отпало настроение учиться с самого начала.

Спасибо! :)

Comment: В девять лет уже давно пора изучать английский, особенно юному программисту.

Comment: Отличный повод изучить базовый английский.

Comment: Согласен. Видимо, и будем двигаться в эту сторону :)

Comment: И тут мне вспомнился [с++ на языке гопников](http://govnokod.ru/11819)

Comment: учите фундаментальным знаниям, после которых будет вообще все равно какой ЯП изучать. Английский, математика, аналитическое мышление. Для детей есть довольно популярный "графический" язык Scratch - он позволяет понять что такое алгоритм, как его реализовать. Там можно сделать достаточно интересные для детей программы, которые еще можно "увидеть". А на питоне смотреть в консоль - дык у ребенка желание отпадет сразу. https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/editor/?tip_bar=home

Comment: @rusnasonov scratch мне совсем не понравился. Я думал, написать что-нибудь своё на основе тех же blockly, инструментарий там получше, как мне кажется. А насчёт скучной консоли - тут уже я постараюсь сами задачи сделать интересными. Будем писать маленькие игры )

Comment: Вообще, наверно, тут нетрудно написать простенький препроцессор, который у скармливаемого файла будет заменять русские ключевые слова на питоновые английские и результат запускать. Но всё же соглашусь с остальными, лучше английский подучить)

Comment: Я бы посоветовал в этом случае игрушку Human Resource Machine, просто и весело, да и учить странные языки не нужно.

Comment: @bukkojot спасибо, видел ее. Думаю дать, но хочу уже дать работать с текстовым кодом. Странные языки - это питон в целом или моя безумная идея по его переработке? :)

Comment: Почему не KTurtle?

Comment: @bukkojot учить ребенка программировать в машинных кодах выдуманного компьютера?..

Comment: Ассемблер сам по себе - очень простой язык. Процессоров в реальном мире тоже много разных. Так почему бы и не попробовать, тем более, что программирование мышкой (причем удобное, мне понравилось!), а сами задачи постепенно увеличивают сложность и поданы в красивой игровой форме?

Comment: @ВладимирРатушненко, по поводу ключевых слов. Все-таки в Python ключевых слов не так много, изучение их не равнозначно изучению английского языка. Я в младшем школьном возрасте изучал Spectrum Basic, интереса к программированию было много, и английские ключевые слова совсем не были проблемой.

Answer (score 8):

Похоже, что это невозможно. Язык Python не включает в себя механизмов для переопределения ключевых слов.

Вольно перевожу [ответ с enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17489759/2790048):

1. Ключевые слова — жестко заданная часть языка. Вы можете написать свой собственный язык или интерпретатор, но переопределить ключевые слова в Python не можете (а в Lisp или C/C++ смогли бы).
2. Это и не нужно. [Язык программирования — это английский](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/hacker-howto.html#skills4). Это может быть не очень честно, но это так. Вся документация — на английском, все методы во всех библиотеках — тоже. Цитируя Эрика Стивена Реймонда (ссылка выше):

   > Английский — рабочий язык хакерского сообщества и интернета, и вам придется изучить его, чтобы стать частью этого сообщества.
   >
   > Линус Торвальдс, финн по национальности, комментирует свой код на английском. (Похоже, что он никогда и не пытался делать иначе.) То, что он хорошо владеет английским, помогло ему собрать международное сообщество разработчиков Линукса. Это поучительный пример.

Добавлю от себя: конструкциями вроде `ЕслиТоВыполнить("вывести('да, это правда')")` вы прячете реальный красивый и лаконичный синтаксис языка и заменяете его уродливым и неестественным. Синтаксис Python приближен к естественным языкам, а они формируют наше сознание и мышление. Нам попросту легче изучать языки программирования, которые похожи на нашу речь.

`ЕслиТоВыполнить(оценить(вы будете применить(ребенок, обучение таким образом)), вернуть(ему будет значительно сложнее учиться))`.

Comment: Спасибо! Значит будем работать с тем, что есть :) Да, получившийся результат меня тоже не удовлетворил. Поэтому, я и ищу лучшие варианты :)

Comment: @ВладимирРатушненко пожалуйста. Научите ребенка задавать хорошие вопросы на StackOverflow, тут он как раз сможет на русском спрашивать. Совсем юные участники у нас редко, но бывают.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы твердо решили научить ребенка плохому и испортить ему жизнь, то такая мелочевка как "невозможность переопределить ключевые слова" не должна останавливать истинного родителя. Следует вспомнить, что исходные коды языка открыты и могут быть модифицированы. Причем вы можете не только приготовить патчсет для себя, но и выложить его на Гитхаб, чтобы другие родители тоже могли повторить свой опыт.

Если банальной локализации будет недостаточно, то можно пойти дальше и начать применять сторонние патчи, которые меняют синтаксис или добавляют новые, уникальные методы, которых в нормальном языке нет и с отсутствием которых во внешнем мире ребенок рано или поздно столкнется.

Можно пойти еще более жестоким образом и сразу изучать язык 1С - язык на русском языке как вы и хотите, бухгалтерия нужна почти везде, в ряде регионов на рынке труда нужны только 1С-ники, при желании на 1С можно писать игры и даже сложные утилитки, да и даже английский можно не учить - все равно за полями и лесами и высокими горами про такой язык и не слыхивали, потому и помощи от англоговорящих можно и не ждать.

Comment: Изменить исходники мне даже в голову не приходило. Спасибо, надо будет подумать об этом. А к 1с у меня какая-то личная неприязнь. Да простят меня 1с-ники. Да и вы можете назвать меня извращенцем за то, что я хочу "перевести" питон. А я назову извращенцем вас за саму идею писать игры на 1с :D

Comment: Когда человек заперт в своем внутреннем мире и не имеет подходящих средств самовыражения, то, как говорится, "голь на выдумки хитра". И будет он на 1с писать игры, утилиты и многое другое, так как больше знать ничего не будет. Над ним за это все будет смеяться и издеваться, от чего его жизнь станет чуточку  отвратительнее. Зато он сможет учавствовать в спец.олимпиадах по написанию кода на экзотических языках. И админ, запретивший запуск всего, кроме 1с, ему не помешает играть на работе.

Comment: это аж как-то грустно :D Если это ваша история - держитесь! Будем вместе извращенцами :D

Comment: Лично я 1с только собираюсь учить, так как в своем ауле не могу найти никакой другой работы для программиста, зато видел нечто подобное на примере других людей не один раз.

Comment: @ВладимирРатушненко если вы вдруг не поняли, весь ответ - сарказм и вредные советы в жанре Остера. )

Answer (score -2):

Можно.

```
введи = input

переменная = введи()
```

будет работать

Comment: Будет, но только с функциями и прочими штуками, которые являются объектами. С конструкциями языка вроде `for` и `while` работать не будет.